# Create two keyboard shortcuts for same menu bar item

Tags: macos, high-sierra, shortcut

I want to use both <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to hide Notes.app (relaunching Notes.app takes some time and I'm used to other applications not quitting when all windows are closed), but apparently in System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts I can only assign one keyboard shortcut to it.

Is there any way for me to assign both keyboard shortcut to the same menu bar item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to assign both keyboard shortcut to the same menu bar item?

Though normal methods I would have to say no, and I do not know of an abnormal method that would allow it either.

---

### Alternate Solution

1. Create an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* with settings:

- **Workflow receives [no input] in [Notes]**

2. Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code* with:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to key code 4 using command down
```

Or use:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to set visible of application process "Notes" to false
```

3. Save the *workflow* as, e.g.,: **Hide Windows in Notes**
4. In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **App Shortcuts**, add one for **Notes** and the **Close** *menu title* setting it *keyboard shortcut* to: **⌘U**
5. In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, set the *keyboard shortcut* for, e.g., **Hide Windows in Notes** to: **⌘W**

Now when in **Notes** and you press **⌘W** it hides the *windows* instead of closing the *window*.

**Notes:**

On some versions of **macOS** there is a *bug* in the *naming convention* of an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* in that *spaces* cause the *Quick Action/Service* not to show in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**. The workaround is to not use *spaces* in the *name* of the *Quick Action/Service*.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** and an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

[image]